# When an option is exercised, does the transaction show up on a TradingView chart?

Tags: options, stock-markets, price, chart, market-data

I’m trying to understand the stock market and chart data. When an option is exercised, does the transaction show up on a TradingView chart?

Example: If Tesla is trading at $423 and someone exercises an option to buy 100 shares at $320, would that transaction be included in the chart for Tesla? Maybe as a long wick of a candle?

Comment: What are "charts like trading view"? How are these charts different from charts found elsewhere? Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the various strike prices for today's TSLA expiration.  The lowest ITM call with open interest is $20 and the highest ITM put with open interest is $760, with 1000s of contracts between these extreme limits and current price.

If any of these were exercised (about 7% of all contracts are exercised), one would expect to see really screwed up price charts with bars (or candles) with an expiration day high/low range of 100s of dollars. That never happens.

The short answer?  Exercised contracts are not included in price charts.